# Android view is null object reference inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i'm having a hard time with some code. I am using sliding tabs with 2 fragment. Inside one of my fragment i'm trying to get a LinearLayout and add some stuff in it but everytime i try to do `getView().findViewByID()` I got null object reference

I'm calling the function after the onCreateView()  I tried making a variable of type View and putting the View that i inflate in the onCreateView in it but i keeps getting the same error. I also tried putting a if() before to check if view isnt null , but even with this , I get null object reference. Can someone help me ?

```
public class listAlarmFragment extends Fragment{

  public View view = null;
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg, Bundle bundle){
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_alarm,vg,false);
     view = v;
     return v;
  }


   public void showAlarm(Cursor c){
     if(view != null) { //even with that check, I got a null pointer exception
        LinearLayout baseList = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.baseList); // NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference
      }
   }
 }
```

Replacing view with getView() doesnt change anything. 
This is how I'm calling the function from the Main Activity

```
   pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Fragment c = adapter.getItem(0);
         ((listAlarmFragment)(c)).showAlarm(dbHelper.getAlarm()); // where I call the function
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

I'm opening this fragment at the beggining when my app open. It crashs when im trying to switch to another fragment.

here is the stack trace :

```
04-02 18:41:54.615 31584-31584/al.demo.alarmmanagerdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: al.demo.alarmmanagerdemo, PID: 31584
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at al.demo.alarmmanagerdemo.fragment.listAlarmFragment.showAlarm(listAlarmFragment.java:83)
                                                                          at al.demo.alarmmanagerdemo.MainActivity$1.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:54)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1971)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:689)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:673)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2288)
                                                                          at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10779)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2858)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2534)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:605)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1895)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3241)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:67)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:67)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:567)
                                                                          at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:11008)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5155)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5007)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4551)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4684)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4559)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4741)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4551)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4559)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7024)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6985)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7202)
                                                                          at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                          at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
04-02 18:41:54.615 31584-31584/al.demo.alarmmanagerdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1510)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
```

Comment: `I'm calling the function after the onCreateView()` - where is this code? Also post the stack trace.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Sorry I missed that part of your comment the first time I read it, I added the stack trace as well  @MarkKeen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this,

```
public class listAlarmFragment extends Fragment{

  //public View view = null; // no need
  private LinearLayout baseList; 
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg, Bundle bundle){
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_alarm,vg,false);
     baseList = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.baseList);
     //view = v; no need
     return v;
  }


   public void showAlarm(Cursor c){
     if(baseList!=null){
     //do something with your baseList 
     }
   }
 }
```

Also check R.id.baseList exists in the layout xml R.layout.list_alarm.
and it should be LinearLayout with

```
id=@+id/baseList
```

Comment: Exactly what I would have suggested. The OP might want to check `if (baseList != null)` before the do anything with it inside the `showAlarm` metnod just to be safe.

Comment: This `check R.id.baseList exists in the layout xml R.layout.list_alarm` is enough to answer the question, the rest is simply code style - if `baseList` is used in only one method there is no need to make it an instance variable, local is fine.

Comment: thanks @Barns. I have added your suggestion to the answer

Comment: @MarkKeen, totally agree.

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work, the variable is okay inside the onCreateView function but when i get into the showAlarm, it is null . I have updated the question with showing how I call the showAlarm function if it can help

Comment: this means the fragment has been destroyed and is no longer in memory. You need to rethink about how to handle fragments

Comment: Ohhhh thanks for telling me that ! I reviewed my code and indeed I have found a place where the fragment get destroyed and remake. It now works perfectly ! thanks

Comment: @Matriac, fragments can be so tricky sometimes. Glad to know it solved your issue